# onClickListener conflict with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, onclick, android-cardview, touch-event

guys, I want to make the onTouchListner to work correctly with onClickListner in a CardView.I have set an onClickListener for a CardView and I have also set an onTouchListner for the imageview inside of that CardView.But I found out that it will execute onclick and onTouch functions at same time if I click on the imageView. The ImageView should only use for stared a event. The click of cardview should enter into another activity to display more details about that event.

The files attached below please take a look.

```
<event.bruce.com.eventfetcher.view.MyCardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/event_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                 />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/event_image"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/event_image">
                <event.bruce.com.eventfetcher.view.CustomCircleImageViewView
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:src="@drawable/share"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    app:civ_border_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:civ_fill_color="#FFFFFF"
                    />

                <event.bruce.com.eventfetcher.view.CustomCircleImageViewView
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/star"
                    android:src="@drawable/star"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    app:civ_border_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:civ_fill_color="#FFFFFF"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/display_month"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SEP."
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/display_date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="28"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:typeface="normal"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                     />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</event.bruce.com.eventfetcher.view.MyCardView>
```

Here is where I set onClickListener and onTouchLister.

```
 public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        cardView.setRadius(12);
        cardView.setCardElevation(8);
        cardView.setContentPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        event_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_image);


        event_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
       //event_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        star = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.star);
        share = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);

        star.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                int action = ev.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_DOWN");

                      //Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), 
                       "Login 
                        successfull" + User.getUserInstance().getUserName(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimator = 
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(star, "scaleX", 1f, 0.5f, 
                        1f);
                        ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimator = 
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(star, "scaleY", 1f, 0.5f, 
                        1f);
                        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                        set.play(scaleXAnimator).with(scaleYAnimator);
                        set.setDuration(250);
                        set.start();

                        starEvent((int) v.getTag(), star);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_MOVE");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_UP");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_CANCEL");
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        share.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                int action = ev.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //Save event to server
                        int eventPos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        Event touchedEvent = api.results.get(eventPos);
                        showShare(touchedEvent);
                        //After saved
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_DOWN");

                        ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimator = 
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(share, "scaleX", 1f, 0.5f, 
                        1f);

                        ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimator = 
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(share, "scaleY", 1f, 0.5f, 
                        1f);
                        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();

                        set.play(scaleXAnimator).with(scaleYAnimator);
                        set.setDuration(250);
                        set.start();

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_MOVE");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_UP");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent action:ACTION_CANCEL");
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        display_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_date);
        display_month = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_month);

    }
```

And in the onBindViewHolder I have set an onClickListener for the entire cardview itself.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int 
 position) {
//BitmapUtils bitmapUtils = new BitmapUtils(MyApplication.getContext());
    holder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
    ((MyViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new 
       View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("Image path", "" + api.results.get(position).image_url);
            uiListener.startDetailActivity(api.results.get(position));
        }
    });




  ((MyViewHolder)holder).event_name.setText(api.results.get(position).name);
    Date latestDate = getMostDate((ArrayList<Event.Schedule>) 
    api.results.get(position).getSchedules());
    api.results.get(position).setLatestDate(latestDate);

    ((MyViewHolder) holder).share.setTag(position);
    ((MyViewHolder) holder).star.setTag(position);

    String latestDateMonth = StringUtils.getMonth(latestDate);
    String latestDateDay = String.valueOf(latestDate.getDate());
    ((MyViewHolder) holder).display_month.setText(latestDateMonth);
    ((MyViewHolder) holder).display_date.setText(latestDateDay);

    if(!isWorkForFavourite) {
        if (staredApi != null) {
            if (isEventInFavourite(api.results.get(position))) {
                ((MyViewHolder) 
     holder).star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_pressed);
            } else {
                ((MyViewHolder) 
     holder).star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
            }
        } else {
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        }
    }else{

      ((MyViewHolder)holder).star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_pressed);
    } 
 if (api.results.get(position).image_url != null && api.results.get(position).image_url.length() > 0) {
        Picasso.with(MyApplication.getContext())
                .load(api.results.get(position).image_url)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.preload_image)
                .error(R.drawable.imageunavailable)
                .into(((MyViewHolder) holder).event_image);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(MyApplication.getContext())
                .load("https://cdn.evbstatic.com/s3-build/perm_001/f8c5fa/django/images/discovery/default_logos/4.png")
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.preload_image)
                .error(R.drawable.imageunavailable)
                .into(((MyViewHolder) holder).event_image);
    }


}
```

Comment: Do your touch listeners work after it view is recycled?

Comment: Another thing: there's no need to use OnTouchListener if you're capture only action down event. You can use onClickListener instead.

Comment: I think it would be better just to have one touch listener and work out the touch X and Y relative to ViewHolder and then do an action based on the touch location, multiple touchlisteners and OnClickListener just gets messy.

Comment: Both onClickListener and onTouchListener all perfomed its. But  The only problem is onTouchListener didn't intercept the cardview's onClick listener. The correct logic is that imageview only response to its onTouch and not respond to cardview's onclick.

Answer (score 0):

use onLongClickListener instead of onClickListener

Comment: So `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` in a touch listener won't fire as well then?